# Can't log in in my user account - apache2 not start within 20 seconds - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, login

I'm trying to log in in any user account and I just can't. When I enter the password of any admin account or even when I try to enter in the Guest account, a black screen appear showing:

```
* The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems.
*Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7 [ OK ]
*Starting Red5 Server red5 [ OK ] 
*Starting daemon monitor monit [ OK ]
```

After this black screen (which disappear in 1 second) it back to the log in screen. I can't read the log files (at least I don't know how), and can't open any user account or guest account. Anyone has an idea of how to solve this? (This is happening on ubuntu 14.04 64bits)

Comment: Are you hosting a web-sever deliberately?  can you reboot into safemode, and issue the command passwd, on any of the existing users?

Comment: Already tried that @j0h and doesn't work.

Comment: what part of that doesnt work? we need details to help you. Please describe what happens, in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you used any of the virtual terminals? `tty1` - `tty6`?

You can switch to them by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F1` through `F6` (`F7` takes you back to the graphical environment)

Can you log in using this method? If so it would be useful to check the logs for errors. please post comment for further info/help.

**UPDATE 0**: Hello there, first, while logged in on `tty1` please execute the following command:

`sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

second, while logged in on `tty2` execute this other command:

`sudo tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

third, on `tty3` execute this other command:

`tail -f ${HOME}/.xsession-errors`

If the file `.xsession-errors` exists then it already contains info on the problem you're having. Now change back to the graphical environment `tty7` with `Alt + F7` and attempt to login, then change back to `tty1`, `tty2` and `tty3` and check for any changes and/or error messages. Post any error messages back here!

Comment: Yes, I can access `tty1` though `Ctrl + Alt + F1` command. How can I see the log from here?

Comment: Thank you for the help, a friend formated the computer without my permission. But that helped me to know how to proceed in the future. Thank you very much

Comment: That's why we're here for! Cheers!