# Ubuntu won't boot ufter upgrade to 15.04, stuck on gnome display manager

Tags: boot, gnome, 15.04

I' a novice so please be specific if you are able to help me. I was running Ubuntu 14.10 with gnome when it prompted me to upgrade to 15.04, which I did. The install is essentially stuck. When I boot I get the following:

Bios etc
Then the purple Ubuntu splash screen (with the dots, not login)
The a whole lot of text with OK next to it from the upgrade
Then is stops on Gnome display manager

I have heard there are issues with Gnome and 15.04, is there a way to boot into Unity? I can access grub but have no idea what i'm doing, recovery mode didn't work and trying the older OS didn't work either

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Visit this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691239/cant-log-in-in-my-user-account-apache2-not-start-within-20-seconds-ubuntu-1/691256#691256) and do the steps that I mentioned in the answer, please post back any messages for further info/help!